# Get maximum userland application-address on Linux

Tags: linux

With Windows you have `GetSysteminfo( SYSTEM_INFO * )`. And inside the `SYSTEM_INFO` structure there are the members `lpMinimumApplicationAddress` and `lpMaximumApplicationAddress`. On a AMD64-system this corresponds to 64kB and `2 ^ 47 - 1` bytes .

Is there a similar call for Linux-systems?